Receiving an RTSP stream with a custom codec in Python (on Windows)
I am building a pyside application on windows and I am trying to receive an rtsp stream carrying data encoded in a custom codec. I've tried a few things that didn't work, so I need some help.
I first tried using opencv with a gstreamer backend. I'm already doing this to receive a video stream, but when I try to receive my custom codec, opencv fails to even open the stream. Here's the code that just tries to open the stream:
import os
import cv2

gst = f"rtspsrc location={rtsp_url} ! appsink"

os.environ["GST_DEBUG"] = "3"
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(gst, cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER)

if cap.isOpened():
    while True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()

        key = cv2.waitKey(1)

        if key & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

        print(frame)
else:
    print("failed to open stream")

which produces this output:
0:00:00.156754700 25048 0000020BB33DCBC0 FIXME                default gstutils.c:4089:gst_element_decorate_stream_id_internal:<fakesrc0> Creating random stream-id, consider implementing a deterministic way of creating a stream-id
0:00:03.694289100 25048 0000020BB38135C0 WARN                 default gst/parse/grammar.y:918:gst_parse_no_more_pads:<rtspsrc0> warning: Delayed linking failed.
0:00:03.698133300 25048 0000020BB38135C0 WARN                 default gst/parse/grammar.y:918:gst_parse_no_more_pads:<rtspsrc0> warning: failed delayed linking some pad of GstRTSPSrc named rtspsrc0 to some pad of GstAppSink named appsink0
0:00:03.705085500 25048 0000020BB33DCC40 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3177:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc1> error: Internal data stream error.
0:00:03.708917300 25048 0000020BB33DCC40 WARN                 basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3177:gst_base_src_loop:<udpsrc1> error: streaming stopped, reason not-linked (-1)
[ WARN:0@4.657] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:2839 cv::handleMessage OpenCV | GStreamer warning: Embedded video playback halted; module udpsrc1 reported: Internal data stream error.
[ WARN:0@4.666] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1698 cv::GStreamerCapture::open OpenCV | GStreamer warning: unable to start pipeline
[ WARN:0@4.667] global cap_gstreamer.cpp:1173 cv::GStreamerCapture::isPipelinePlaying OpenCV | GStreamer warning: GStreamer: pipeline have not been created
[ WARN:0@4.667] global cap.cpp:206 cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(GSTREAMER): backend is generally available but can't be used to capture by name
failed to open stream

The thing is, the pipeline runs fine without errors in the command line using gst-launch-1.0. I assume cv2.videoCapture can only be given video frame formats? I really don't know.
I then tried using python bindings for gstreamer, but there doesn't seem to be any such bindings that work on Windows. I know I can use WSL, but I'm too deep into my development to now set everything up again in WSL. That said, I did a short test in WSL just to see if it would work, and it does. Here's the code I used:
import gi
from threading import Thread
import struct

gi.require_version('Gst', '1.0')
gi.require_version("GstApp", "1.0")

from gi.repository import Gst, GstApp, GLib

_ = GstApp

Gst.init()

main_loop = GLib.MainLoop()
main_loop_thread = Thread(target=main_loop.run)
main_loop_thread.start()

pipeline = Gst.parse_launch("rtspsrc location=rtsp_url ! appsink name=sink")

appsink = pipeline.get_by_name("sink")

pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)

try:
    while True:
        sample = appsink.try_pull_sample(Gst.SECOND)
        if sample is None:
            print("no sample")
            continue
        
        buf = sample.get_buffer()
        result, mapinfo = buf.map(Gst.MapFlags.READ)
        dat = mapinfo.data

        datum = dat[12:]

        x, y, worn = struct.unpack("!ffB", datum)
        print(x, y)

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("stopping")
    pass


pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
main_loop.quit()
main_loop_thread.join()

Does anyone know if I can get this working with opencv? Or if there is any way to run gstreamer code in python on windows? I'd appreciate any help I can get, I've been pulling my hair out for days. Thanks.
EDIT: some clarification
Regarding the custom codec, I honestly don’t know if “codec” is really the right word here. But basically each rtp packet has 21 bytes, the last 9 of which are used to store two floats and a Boolean. So really all I need is a way to get those rtp packets, then I can process them myself in Python (which is what I do in the second code above). I don’t need a custom gstreamer build and/or plugin.
As for opencv, I’m trying to use it because I’m already using it to stream video from an ip camera, and it’s the only way I know of to run a gstreamer pipeline in Python on windows. The reason I’d like to use gstreamer is because it has given me the best performance in terms of latency and stability, which I need in order to achieve real-time streams. The device I’m streaming from has a Python api for receiving the streams, and it performs horribly (growing delay and heavy cpu load). The api uses the aiortsp library to do some “network stuff” which I don’t understand. Given that it performs badly, I’m hesitant to try to establish manual connection myself in a similar manner out of fear of bad performance. All this is to say I’d prefer to stick to gstreamer.

I honestly don't see how involving OpenCV in the picture could make this any easier. Unless you want to do some actual computer vision work, then it's the wrong choice of a library.

"receive my custom codec" -- Can you elaborate on that? If it's a custom codec... do you have  some custom build of gstreamer that supports it? Please, elaborate.

@DanMašek Thanks a bunch for the replies, I’ve edited the post with some clarification.

Very easy use pyav Just demux them without decoding, why you are using a media Protocol for data thats a diffrent thing. gg when you publish the stream the payload of the rtp package should not use Video or audio. I Always avoid opencv use pyav you get Windows Support and also ffmpeg or gstreamer Performance because its ffmpeg c bindings
